# ItextSharp-Exception in the reader initialization "The document has no page root"

Tags: c#, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

Hi i'm trying to read various pdf files with ItextSharp.dll, some of them throws me an exception when I try to read it. the exception is this: "The document has no page root (meaning: it's an invalid PDF).". I made some tests in the Merge example, in the Itext web page([Merge-Example](http://demo.itextsupport.com/MergeServer/)) and these are successful. So, can someone guide me to see what am I doing wrong?
This is my code:

```
public void MergeFiles(String[] strFiles, String strFileresult)
    {
        Document document = new Document(); ;
        PdfCopy copy;

        copy = new PdfCopy(document, new FileStream(strFileresult, FileMode.Create));
        document.Open();

        PdfReader[] reader = new PdfReader[3];

        for (int i = 0; i < strFiles.Count(); i++)
        {

            reader[i] = new PdfReader(strFiles[i]);
            copy.AddDocument(reader[i]);
        }
        document.Close();
        for (int i = 0; i < reader.Count(); i++)
        {
            reader[i].Close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what's causing your exact problem but once we get rid of the unnecessary internal arrays and switch to the `using` pattern to get automatic cleanup everything works just fine.

```
public void MergeFiles(string[] strFiles, String strFileresult) {
    using( var document = new Document()) {
        using (var copy = new PdfCopy(document, new FileStream(strFileresult, FileMode.Create))) {

            document.Open();

            foreach( var file in strFiles) {
                using (var reader = new PdfReader(file)) {
                    copy.AddDocument(reader);
                }
            }

            document.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i try your method, but keeps throwing the same exception in this line "using (var reader = new PdfReader(file))".
This exceptions only occurs with some files, but the strange thing is that: the test page  is processing ok the conflict file.

Comment: Can you post the problem file for us to inspect?

Comment: sure this is the file. [PDF] (https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B76us6MtUwziNFJKUkxwczlQTkE&usp=sharing)

Comment: @AgustinCedeño I just checked. That document has a page root, so something else is at play. I don't know what's wrong, but that document should work correctly.

Comment: thanks for the reply, as my post says I check the Itext example and the file works fine, but in my scenario is throwing the same exception. I updated the method, as @ChrisHaas suggest to me, but nothing different happens.

Comment: we(CEMEX) purchase the licence since a year ago, and we got the same problem with a few files, any one knows if exist a way to receive support in a more personal way?